# How to copy the elements of an array into an array in a Mongodb document

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have an array

```
 let data = [a, b, c, d, e];
```

And I want to insert the elements of this array into an array in a MongoDb document. This is my schema.

```
 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     info: reqString,
     data: [String]
 });
```

As you can see the data field represents an array. In my index.js I use a for-loop to iterate through the array.

```
 for(var i= 0; i < data.length; i++){
     connectToDb(data[i]);
 }
```

And the connectToDb() is here:

```
const connectToMongoDB = async (_data) => {
     await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
     try {
             console.log('Connected to mongodb!');

             await userSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                 info: 'facts',
             }, {
                    $push: {
                         data: _data,
                    }
             });
         } finally {
             mongoose.connection.close();
             console.log('Disconnected from mongodb!');
         }
     });
 }
```

However although a documents is created in MongoDb, the data field which represents the array remains empty. I welcome all suggestions

Comment: Not clear, do you want to set the `data` field value with your data array, or append your data array to the existing array in the `data` field?

Comment: The data array in the MongoDB should initially be empty. I wish to take all the elements from global data array and populate the data array WITHIN the MongoDB document

Comment: Ok, so it is **1.** in my answer

Comment: BTW, supply the whole array without `for` loop: `connectToDb(data);`

Comment: Thank you. I tried both version 1 and version 2. A document is created in mongodb, however the array field remains empty. I also removed the for-loop and sent the global data array directly to connectToDb(data); but this didnt change anything.

Comment: Not clear, do you want to create a new doc with those values, or update an existing doc? `{ info: 'facts' }` suggests the latter

Comment: I want to update the array in an existing document. Prior to this, the array in the MongoDb document would be empty.

Comment: Try adding a `.exec()`

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear if you want to set the `data` field value with your `_data` array, or append your `_data` array to the existing array in the `data` field.

**1.** To replace the array of the `data` field:

```
        await userSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
            { info: 'facts' },
            { $set: { data: _data } }
        ).exec();
```

**2.** To append an array to the array of the `data` field:

```
        await userSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
            { info: 'facts' },
            { $push: { data: { $each: _data } } }
        ).exec();
```